# how to use multiple timers using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net

I am using 2 timers in a single form. Form contains many textboxes, labels and gridview.

One timer is for refresh the gridview and second timer is for print the crystal report I used threading concept but it gives error for labels and other controls.

my code is

```
Private Sub cmdstart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    system.EventArgs) Handles cmdstart.Click

    Dim timer2 As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    AddHandler timer2.Tick, AddressOf mytimer2_tick
    timer2.Enabled = True
    timer2.Interval = 100
    timer2.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub mytimer2_tick(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' my printing code

    DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer).Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub frmList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dim timer1 As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    AddHandler timer1.Tick, AddressOf mytimer1_tick
    timer1.Enabled = True
    timer1.Interval = 10000
End Sub

Public Sub mytimer1_tick(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    RefreshGrid()
    DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer).Enabled = True
End Sub
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the issue is. Using two `Timers` is exactly like using one `Timer` but twice. We can't help you fix the issue if you don't explain what the issue is and you're clouding the issue by talking about threads when there is nothing relating to multi-threading in your code.

Comment: sorry for wrong information. I am new to vb.net. I want to use 2 timers in single form. from first timer for every 2 seconds gridview should refresh and from second timer every 1 second crystal report should print please help me

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: timer1 is working fine. timer2 is not executing.Any other method is there. let me know

Comment: Why are you creating the `Timers` in code to begin with?  Just add them to the form in the designer and configure them in the Properties window.  Regardless, if you want the second `Timer` to `Tick` every second then why have you told it to `Tick` ten times every second?  Also, what does "not executing" mean?  Are you saying that the event handler for the `Tick` event is not being executed?  How exactly are you determining that?